# Elasticsearch Cluster Backup on S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, lucene

What are the best tools for storing Snapshot on S3 periodically(for example per day)  ?

I know elasticsearch  snapshot store only  delta. If I am creating snapshot per day so I will many directories very soon and S3 own cost. Is any way or strategy to reduce cost and space ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks Raf. Initially.I stated manually doing backup on S3  and after that i am trying crontab. don't know This is right way to do backup.

Comment: Best if you edit your question and state that your primary concern is elasticsearch. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need two things:

1. Add the S3 repository.
2. Run the snapshots periodically — [Curator is a great tool for that](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/snapshot.html).

Curator can also [delete snapshots periodically](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/delete_snapshots.html). Though I'm not sure what you mean with "If I am creating per day I will very soon and S3 own cost." Since it's a diff it should be relatively cheap.